# Scroll down in VNC GUI

Tags: vnc, gui

Is anyone know a way to scroll down in VNC remote GUI ?

I cannot access to the bottom of the modal...

[image: VNC scroll down]

Comment: Im not 100% sure, but alt and left mouse button should move the window.

Comment: It's working thank you so much MatsK :-)  Don't hesitate to place your comment as an answer and let me validate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alt and left mouse button should move the window.